# Knapsack questions

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

for leetcode 322 coin change, the code is below:

```
class Solution:
    def change(self, amount: int, coins: List[int]) -> int:
        dp = [0] * (amount + 1)
        dp[0] = 1

        for i in range(len(coins)):
            for j in range(1, amount + 1):
                if coins[i] <= j:
                    dp[j] = dp[j] + dp[j-coins[i]]         
        return dp[-1]
```

for leetcode 1049 last stone weight II, the code is below:

```
class Solution:
    def lastStoneWeightII(self, stones: List[int]) -> int:
        total = sum(stones)
        
        Max_weight = int(total/2)
        print(Max_weight)
        current = (Max_weight+1)*[0]
        
        for stone in stones:
            for wgt in range(Max_weight, -1, -1):
                if wgt-stone>=0:
                    current[wgt] = max(stone + current[wgt-stone], current[wgt])
                print(stone, wgt, current)
            
           
        return total-2*current[-1]
```

I like to understand the logic of knapsack more.  My biggest question mark is how do we decide whether the second "for loop" is in ascending order or descending order.  For example, the first coin change code  [for j in range(1, amount + 1):], it is in ascending order but the second stone weigh code[ for wgt in range(Max_weight, -1, -1):] is in descending order.  I kind of understand why it works after tracing the code but is there a more intuitive way of really explaining why we use ascending or descending for loop when dealing with knapsack problems.  I really not able to grasp the concept of when to use which one....  Thanks!

Comment: all totally depend on the problem and what is the result they want to have

Comment: There is no particular reason for which you need to go in descending order in the second solution, you can just about do it in ascending order too, if that's something you are interested in, I can perhaps write it and i am hoping you understood the methodology behind the solution, since it is a 0 to 1 Knapsack problem

Comment: hi AM429, thank you for the response.  I tried modifying the second loop in ascending order in the stone weight (the second) solution but with no success.  Intuitively thinking, we should divide the problem into small sub problems and work it bigger by adding more items.  However, the stone weight solution that was given to me was the reverse (working from big to small).  That's why I don quite get it.  Do you think you can work on that 1049 leetcode (loast stone weight problem II) and show it to me how that "for loop works" in ascending order.  that would be a great help!!!  thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

They are fundamentally two different problems.

The 322 Coin Change problem is an instance of the Unbounded Knapsack problem -- you have infinite quantities of the items that you want to fit in your knapsack.

The 1049 LastStoneWeightII problem is an instance of the Bounded Knapsack problem -- you have only one instance of each item that you want to fit in your knapsack.

---

The reason you need to run the for loop in descending order in the second problem is because if you don't you will accidentally add the stones more than once. The optimal solution of a subproblem might have already considered the current stone if you run the loop incrementally. But if you run the loop in reverse, you can be sure that the optimal subproblem solution, that you are using to build the solution considering the current stone, does not consist of the current stone.

If you want to use the incrementing for loop for the bounded knapsack problem, you can either use the 2D array version of the algorithm OR you need to keep track of the subset that is part of the solution to each subproblem.

You can find more discussion here: https://leetcode.com/discuss/study-guide/1200320/Thief-with-a-knapsack-a-series-of-crimes.